# ABS Brakes Bleeding

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, silverado, bleeding

I replaced my calipers,pads, rotors, master cylinder, brake mod, hubs on my 2000 Chevy Silverado C1500 when I tried to bleed brakes it would not do anything. No pedal pressure and no fluid when trying to bleed. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Did you bench bleed the master cylinder?

Comment: Yes I did still nothing

Comment: If the master cylinder is bled and the piston is moving it will pump fluid through the lines. I suspect air in cylinder or faulty cylinder.

Comment: I suspect you need to pump the brakes up before bleeding to ensure the calipers are fully extended. Once everything is fully in place, you should start seeing brake fluid.